# Add Generalist badge to "next badge" feature

Tags: feature-request

I really like the "Next badge" feature that was introduced on SO recently; it's nice to see how close you are to grabbing the next venerable badge.

That said, I was hoping that the Generalist badge was among the badges you could pick for your next badge tracker. After a quick check on the [Generalist Progression](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/734/generalist-progression) I realised that I'm actually quite close to achieving it, in fact only one vote separates me :)

The progress could show X / 20, where X is the number of top 40 tags you've earned 15+ votes for.

The guide that explains how to achieve the badge could either:

- pick a top-40 tag in which you have the highest votes but less than 15, or
- pick the top 5 popular tags in which you haven't answered yet

Comment: The problem with Generalist is that it has another site-specific requirement: [It has to have 40 tags with at least 200 questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/255554). This would either have to be tracked too (which would be somewhat demotivating as you can hardly do anything about this) or a lot of people would be confused as to why they did not earn the badge despite meeting all requirements. I think the intention to (finally) change this was announced somewhere here on Meta, but I cannot find it right now.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You mean that the badge overview page for any site mentions Generalist even if it doesn't have 40 tags with at least 200 questions?

Comment: That’s indeed the case, but it’s not the point of my comment.